# Why can't I have an private abstract method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract

Let's say I have my classic:

```
public abstract class Mammal {
    private int numLegs;
    private String voice;
    private Coat coat;

    public abstract void eat();

    public abstract void speak();
    public abstract void sleep();  


    private abstract void ingestFood(Food f);  //The abstract method ingestFood in type Mammal can only set a visibility modifier, one of public or protected
}
```

With these concrete implementations:

```
public class Dog extends Mammal {
     private int numLegs = 4;
     private String voice = "Woof!";
     private Coat coat = new Coat(COATTYPE.FUR, COATCOLOR.BROWN);

     @Override
     public void eat()
     { 
          Rabbit r = chaseRabbits(); 
          if (r != null) ingest(r); 
          else {
                   Garbage g = raidBin(); 
                   if (g!= null) ingest(g); 
               }


     }

     @Override
     private void ingest(Food f)
     {
         gobbleItAllUpInFiveSeconds(f); 
         stillFeelHungry(); 
     }
}

public class Human extends Mammal {
     private int numLegs = 2;
     private String voice = "Howdy!!";
     private Coat coat = new Coat(COATTYPE.SKIN, COATCOLOR.PINK);

     @Override
     public void eat()
     { 
          Food f = gotoSuperMarket();
          ingest(f); 


     }

     @Override
     private void ingest(Food f)
     {
         burp();  
     }
}
```

Now, I want a method in the `Mammal` class that is callable by all instances of the mammal, e.g.

```
public String describe() {
     return "This mammal has " + this.numLegs + "legs, a " + this.coat.getColor() + " " this.coat.getCoatType() + " and says " + this.voice;
}
```

My question is that, by making the `Mammal` class not abstract, is it possible to create a mammal by itself?  E.g.

```
 Mammal me = new Mammal();
```

You shouldn't be able to do this.

However, I do want to have some public methods that are implemented by the parent class that all subclasses call, but that each call their own private method.

Comment: This won't even compile. 'Mammal' is a normal class, all methods need a body. Apart from that: 'Mammal' isn't abstract.

Comment: You *can* have an abstract class with method implementations, and you wouldn't be able to instantiate it. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: @DaveNewton -Wait you're right, the reason I've asked is because I'm getting this error: `The abstract method genRecord in type AttributeSourceTableDao can only set a visibility modifier, one of public or protected`

Comment: @dwjohnston Think about that - what exactly would a `Dog` do with a `Mammal` private method?

Comment: @jdphenix yeah, I was a bit confused about the compiler error I was getting, will update the questiont hough, given that I can't delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally have implemented methods in an abstract class:

"Abstract classes are similar to interfaces. You cannot instantiate them, and they may contain a mix of methods declared with or without an implementation."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 5):

Responding to the question in the title ("*Why can't I have an private abstract method?*") :

You can't have a `private abstract` method, because `abstract` methods need to be implemented in subclasses. But `private` methods are not visible in subclasses.

(If you want to have a method that is only visible in a subclass, and not publically, then you need to make the methods `protected`)

So you couldn't implement a `private abstract` method, ever. That's why Java doesn't allow them - they wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your unimplemented methods as abstract if you want them to behave differently on child classes, and the methods to be inherit leave them like a normal method. Also use protected instead of private to be accessible to inherited classes:

```
public abstract class Mammal
{
  protected int numLegs;
  protected String voice;
  protected Coat coat;

  abstract void eat();
  abstract void speak();
  abstract void sleep();

  public String describe()
  {
     return "This mammal has " + this.numLegs + "legs, a " 
     + this.coat.getColor() + " " this.coat.getCoatType() + " and says " + this.voice;
  }
}
```

And use constructors to initialize variables and implement abstract methods:

```
public class Dog extends Mammal
{
  public Dog(){
     this.numLegs = 4;
     this.voice = "Woof!";
     this.coat = new Coat(COATTYPE.FUR, COATCOLOR.BROWN);
  }
  void eat(){
    System.out.println("eating like a dog");
  }
  void speak(){
    System.out.println("speaking like a dog");
  }
  void sleep(){
    System.out.println("sleeping like a dog");
  }
}

public class Human extends Mammal
{
  public Human(){
     this.numLegs = 2;
     this.voice = "Howdy!!";
     this.coat = new Coat(COATTYPE.SKIN, COATCOLOR.PINK);
  }
  void eat(){
    System.out.println("eating like a human");
  }
  void speak(){
    System.out.println("speaking like a human");
  }
  void sleep(){
    System.out.println("sleeping like a human");
  }
}
```